# print array element using foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my view i have

```
forach($array as $arr)    
{
$data = array('fname' => $arr['first_name'],lname => $arr['lname']);    
<input type="hidden" value="<?php print_r($data);?>" name="fnameData[]">    
}
```

Now i am submitting form to controller and print print_r($this->input->post(fnameData)) it prints following array

```
Array(

    [0] => Array([fname] => abc lname => aaa)
    [1] => Array([fname] => xyz lname => bbb)

)
```

Now I want to print fname and lname both using `foreach loop` in controller

It gives me Illegal string offset 'fname'

Comment: Well you have an answer, but im amazed you couldnt have worked this out - its really fundamental stuff.

Comment: agree with @user574632

Comment: `print_r` is only really for debugging. And `var_dump` is usually a better choice - if you had used that we would have spotted the error sooner. The problem is in your view. you are dumping a string representation of an array (not an actual array) into the input value. You can not do that, an input can only contain a single value in html. Either create more inputs to hold the values, or use some serialization each side (eg json_encode / decode)

Answer (score 7):

Simple

```
foreach($your_array as $arr)
{
    echo $arr['fname'];
}
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<?php
forach($array as $arr)    
{
  $data = $arr['first_name'];  
 ?> 
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data;?>" name="fnameData[]">    
 <?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: when i am printing like this it is showing error Illegal string offset 'fname'

Comment: i have updated question again if now i want to print fname and lname both what can i do

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value["fname"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  foreach($array as $arr)
  {
    $data = $arr['first_name'];
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data;?>" name="first_name[]"> 

<?php
  }
?>
```